# Issue with Dynamic Component Loading in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I have a dialoganchor as Directive as below

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[dialogAnchor]'
})
export class DialogAnchorDirective {
    constructor(
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
    ) {}

    createDialog(dialogComponent: { new(): DialogComponent }): ComponentRef<DialogComponent> {
        this.viewContainer.clear();

        const dialogComponentFactory =
          this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(dialogComponent);
        const dialogComponentRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(dialogComponentFactory);

        dialogComponentRef.instance.close.subscribe(() => {
            dialogComponentRef.destroy();
        });
        // setTimeout( () => {
        //   dialogComponentRef.destroy();
        // }, 5000);
        return dialogComponentRef;
    }
}
```

by using this i am loading DialogComponent Dynamically
i am calling above dialog Anchor in my application components as follows

```
this.dialogAnchor.createDialog(DialogComponent);
```

but in above line showing error as
**[ts] Argument of type 'typeof DialogComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new () => DialogComponent'.**

DialogComponent code is below

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'dlg',
    template: `
    <div class="dialog" [ngClass]="{'stu-success':dlgProps.msgType == 'success','stu-error':dlgProps.msgType == 'fail',
    'stu-warn':dlgProps.msgType == 'warn','stu-info':dlgProps.msgType == 'info'}" >
        <header><div class="title">Dialog box</div><div class="exit-button" (click)="onClickedExit()">x</div></header>
        <p>Hi XXXXXXXX</p>
    </div>
    `,
    styles: [`
        .dialog {
            width: 250px;
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 5px;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: fixed;
            left: calc(50% - 125px);
            top: 100px;
        }
        .dialog p {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .dialog header {
            border-bottom: 1px solid black;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 5px;
            display: flex;
        }
        .dialog header .title {
            flex-grow: 1;
            cursor: default;
        }
        .dialog header .exit-button {
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 0 5px;
        }
        .stu-success {
          background: green;
        }
        .stu-error {
          background: #ff0000;
        }
        .stu-warn{
          background: orange;
        }
        .stu-info {
          background: yellow;
        }
    `]
})
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {
    dlgProps: any;
    constructor(private appService: AppService) {
    }
    close = new EventEmitter();

    ngOnInit() {
      this.dlgProps = this.appService.dlgProps;
    }

    onClickedExit() {
        this.close.emit('event');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you defining `dialogComponent` as `{new(): DialogComponent}`?

Comment: passing it as a JSON Object, it means creating new DialogComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define `dialogComponent` as `new(): DialogComponent` you're saying: *'give me a class of type `DialogComponent` that has a parameterless constructor`*.

As you see, it's not the case because `DialogComponent` has a constructor with parameters.

So, either you define `createDialog` as:

```
createDialog(dialogComponent: { new(AppService): DialogComponent }): ComponentRef<DialogComponent>
```

Or you just do this:

```
createDialog(dialogComponent: Type<DialogComponent>): ComponentRef<DialogComponent>
```

which in my opinion is far easier. This way you can create dialogs even for derived classes of `DialogComponent`, regardless of the number of parameters.

If you use the second approach be sure to import `Type` from `@angular/core`.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr.Oscar Paz, will work and give update shortly

Comment: @OOOOOOOOOOscar Paz, It is working fine  .                                                                                            999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 times thank you